# Execute several queries and save them to files in Bash

Tags: bash, google-bigquery

I wrote the following bash script to run queries saved in files and save them to csv files. The queries have to be run against a BigQuery database. I use the `bq`-cli for this purpose ([link to documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference)). The script looks as follows:

```
#/bin/bash

# Setup filepaths:
ROOT="/app"
QUERIES="${ROOT}/queries"
RAW="${ROOT}/tmp/raw"

# Setup query paths:
Q1="${QUERIES}/query1.sql"
Q2="${QUERIES}/query2.sql"
Q3="${QUERIES}/query3.sql"
Q4="${QUERIES}/query4.sql"
Q5="${QUERIES}/query5.sql"

# Setup target paths:
F1="${RAW}/file1.csv"
F2="${RAW}/file2.csv"
F3="${RAW}/file3.csv"
F4="${RAW}/file4.csv"
F5="${RAW}/file5.csv"

for ((i=1;i<=5;i++))
do
    command="(bq query -q --use_legacy_sql=false --format=csv --max_rows=100000 --format=csv < \$Q${i}) > \$F${i}"
    eval "$command"
done
```

I would like to optimize the script concerning speed, maintainability and robustness. Specifically, I wonder if there is a better way than using `eval` within the loop?

Comment: Speed is fine. Robustness mostly depends on your commands and not bash. Maintainability and readability, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You should never need to use `eval`. Instead of

```
command="(bq query -q --use_legacy_sql=false --format=csv --max_rows=100000 --format=csv < \$Q${i}) > \$F${i}"
eval "$command"
```

use the more readable

```
bq query -q --use_legacy_sql=false --format=csv --max_rows=100000 --format=csv <"${QUERIES}/query${i}.sql" >"${RAW}/file${i}.csv"
```

If you want to customize paths past the numbers you're using, you can learn about bash arrays.